# LISP appending item to array from a for loop

Tags: lisp

I'm trying to add an item to an array if this item is not already in the array. Essentially what I want to achieve is to iterate through a list remove any duplicates by checking if they already exist.

Here's how I've started:

```
(defun reduce(mylist)

    (setq newList (list ()) )
    (loop for item in mylist 
        do (


            (if (not (member item newList))


            )


        ))


)

(reduce '(3 4 5 4 5))
```

The error I'm getting is `(IF (NOT (MEMBER 'ITEM 'NEWLIST))) should be a lambda expression`. I know this is something to do with how `item` and `newList` are being accessed and can't figure out how to correct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused by wrapping the body of the `do` form with parentheses. Parens have meaning in lisp, so 'extra' wrapping like this will break the code.

There are some other mistakes. `setq` is used to assign to an unbound variable. You should use `let` to establish a binding instead. The initial value of that variable is a one-length list containing `()`, while it should probably just be `()`.

`reduce` is already a Common Lisp function, so a difference choice of name would be a good idea.

Finally, the formatting isn't either idiomatic or consistent - you have `mylist` and `newList`. A lisp programmer would spell these names `my-list` and `new-list`.

Here's how it might look when cleaned up a bit. I've left some important parts out for you to fill in.

```
(defun unique-elements (list)
  (let ((result ()))
    (loop for item in list
          do (when (not (member item result))
               ...))
    ...))
```

(It would be cleaner to use `loop`'s collection machinery for this job, but I decided an example of how to use `do` would be more helpful.)

Comment: Wow, there's still lots to learn here. Thank you very much for this concise answer.